# Integer columns not accepted in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF pipeline to copy data from data lake to blob storage and then to table storage. Table storage has a column which includes ***integer*** values (column: Age). On trying to query the data in table storage

```
https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/Customers()?$filter=Age%20eq%2030 -> (age 30 is considered as integer)
```

the output is null.

On updating the query to

```
https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/Customers()?$filter=Age%20eq%20'30' -> (age 30 is considered as string)
```

it returned right output.

I used the same adf pipeline to copy data from data lake to cosmos db sql api. When I used query

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Age = 30
```

it returned right output. I tried

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Age > 30
```

it also returned right output.

So, cosmos db is accepting integer columns whereas table storage is only accepting string values. Why is that? How do I resolve this issue in table storage so that it will accept integer columns? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the age type is integer in the storage explorer? I have tested, the integer column could be queried.

Comment: I see age type as string in the storage explorer. Why is that? The age column that I copied from ADF is of integer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure about the cause, the below is my steps to copy a son data from data lake to azure table.

Firstly this is my test JSON:

```
{
    "callingimsi": "466920403025604",
    "switch1": "China",
    "switch2": "Germany",
    "testvalue":12
}
```

Create the JSON Dataset, then below is the default Schema, the testvalue is integer type.

[image]

Then I just create a table dataset and create the simple pipeline, set the source and sink then debug. In the table the testvalue is Int64 type it supports the query.

[image]